# ggplot2: Arrange how stacked bars are being rendered using melt

Tags: r, ggplot2

Assume a frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c("2016-12-31","2017-01-23","2017-03-28","2018-01-01"), Var1 = c(11,22,45,63), Var2 = c(1,2,3,4), Var3 = c(8,9,10,11))
```

then melting our data to create a stacked bar chart:

```
 data <-  reshape2::melt(df,id.vars = 'Date', variable.name = 'series')
```

and then plotting the chart:

```
ggplot(data,aes(
      y = value ,
      x = as.Date(Date),
      fill = series
    )) + geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

which comes out to something like this:
[image]

is there a way to rearrange the bars so that Var3 is on the top and the others following below? So it would be (in this case):

> Var3(blue), Var1(red), Var2(green)

Comment: I think PatL has given you a solution.  However, if I cared I would read the ggplot documentation carefully.  I'll bet there is a way to tell it what colors to use for the stacked bar plot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reorder the levels of factor. Here's a possible solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  mutate(Data = as.Date(Date),
         series = factor(.$series, levels = c("Var3", "Var1", "Var2"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(
    y = value ,
    x = Date,
    fill = series)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

[image]